# How to add real-time video streaming and live chat facilities to a Flutter application for free?

Tags: flutter, socket.io, video-streaming, agora.io, livechat

I want to know how to add real-time video streaming and live chat facilities for free to a Flutter application?

I found `agora_rtm` and `agora_rtc_engine` but I am not sure if they are completely free and open source(I mean all the source codes are available)?

I also like to know if there are any other/better available options? Something that is open source and not related on an external API.

Moreover I want to know what does exactly `socket.io` do? Can we use it in Flutter for both real-time video streaming and live chat purposes?

```
Please either help me to know/understand more or don't do down votes please!
```

Comment: Agora is not free. It is free upto some usage. In production, you definitely have to pay. If you want to build your own real time video chat app, you need to use WebRTC. https://webrtc.org/ go through the link you will have some idea on what to do next

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin: Thank you. Can I also use WebRTC for live chat or it's a better idea to use Socket.io for that part?

Comment: WebRTC supports live chat and any other video communication. AgoraRTC comes with WebRTC. If you do not want to write your own WebRTC code then you can try AgoraRTC.

Answer (score 2):

[Socket.io](https://socket.io) opens channels between clients and server, allowing unprompted messages to be sent between each other. This is great for sending chat, but it is not mean for video streaming. Instead you should look at the [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) standard and the high level packages like [peer.js](https://peerjs.com/) built around it.

Comment: Can I also use WebRTC for live chat or it's a better idea to use Socket.io for that part/

Comment: I think you can use either since WebRTC supports any type of data to be sent between peers.